# How can I select multiple elements from the nth vector in a list?

Tags: r, list, vector, pipe, subset

I am trying to take in a character vector, do some operations on it, and then extract only the elements that match certain criteria.

> c("a", "b", "b") %>% list(., which(.=="b")) %>% {.[[1]][[.[[2]]]]}

the list is made out of the character vector as the first element and an index vector - of the elements I want to extract - as the second element. But, when I try to use list subsetting in the final step, I get the error

> Error in .[[1]][[.[[2]]]] :    attempt to select more than one element
> in vectorIndex

How can I get the desired output:

> c("b", "b")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c("a", "b", "b") %>% list(., which(.=="b")) %>% {.[[1]][ .[[2]] ]}
# [1] "b" "b"
```

However, I would prefer

```
> x <- c('a', 'b', 'b')
> x[which(x == 'b')]
[1] "b" "b"
```

**Doing everything by chaining looks fancy but may sacrifice readability and simplicity.**